# I lost the boot partition, what should I do?

Tags: boot, partitioning

Recently, I dualbooted windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04, then I decided to be able to open the Windows 7 files from within Ubuntu. But I mounted the wrong partition and accidentally deleted it when I realized it was the wrong one... It's only when I restarted my computer that I realized that I deleted the boot partition.
Now, whenever I try to open the PC, it says:
BOOTMGR is missing
Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart

Whenever I try the above command, it eventually restarts and gets back to the same screen. Windows 7 was the main boot screen. I was planning on creating a Windows recovery disc, is it a great idea? Will it work? If not, have any other ideas?

Comment: This is offtopic - I realise you have Ubuntu installed - but this question is about Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to fix two bootloaders:

1. Windows 7 bootmgr and
2. GRUB for Ubuntu.

---

Following are the steps to do so:

1. Insert your Windows Vista or Windows 7 disk into your DVD player and restart your computer.
2. The next screen you see should have the Language, Time and Currency and Keyboard boxes.
3. In the lower left side there are two options: “*What to know before installing Windows*” and “*Repair your computer*.”
4. Click on “*Repair your computer*”.
5. Windows will then try to find the installation directory for Vista or Windows 7, depending on what you have.
6. Next up is a screen with a box called Recovery Options. Click the first option, Startup Repair.
7. You’ll see a Startup Repair box with the message “*Startup Repair is checking your system for problems…”*
8. When it’s done, it will prompt you to reboot. If there is more than one problem it may reboot again to continue repairing.
9. At this point, you can remove the DVD, reboot and everything should be working.

Now you are done with Windows 7 Boot loader. Time to fix GRUB. Do the Following:

You can install GRUB on your hard disk. You can do this by using bootable Ubuntu CD.

Boot to live cd. When you get UBUNTU Live Desktop. Open terminal and type the following

1. `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`
2. `sudo update-grub`
3. `quit`

You are done now. Reboot the machine.

This will install grub on MBR of your hard disk with dual boot. Try the latest Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

---

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System

You can also use the bootrepair tool to reinstall grub:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: This Grub information is for Grub Legacy not Grub2.

Comment: Updated to grub2 now

Comment: Feel free to ask about UBUNTU over here and get yourself unleash to new world of ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

Check the following links to get help on recovering Windows 7 boot files

- http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/windows-7-ultimate-bootmgr-is-missing-ctrlaltdel/a5793c54-1912-445d-9703-8caeca32e6f9
- http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/windows-7-bootmgr-is-missing-resolved-using-winre/8bb148bc-8035-4847-9696-888f7a0a9720

After you successfully recovered Windows 7, you need to recover Grub to be able to boot to Ubuntu. See this questions for that:

- [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Hope this will fix your problem

Comment: @NickRameau Yes, I was a bit lazy to provide more information since the Internet is seems to be flooded with the same topic :-)